# Variable persist outside environment

Tags: conditionals, grouping, xifthen

I am using the `ifthen` package for some conditional formatting. I am storing state in some `booleans`, but it seems that there is an issue with lexical scope. In particular, when a boolean is set within an environment, the value does not persist outside the environment.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}  % or xifthen
\newboolean{bool}
\setboolean{bool}{true}

\begin{document}
Start: \ifthenelse{\boolean{bool}}{T}{F}

\begin{itemize}
\item{item} \ifthenelse{\boolean{bool}}{T}{F}
\setboolean{bool}{false}
\item{item 2} \ifthenelse{\boolean{bool}}{T}{F}
\end{itemize}

End: \ifthenelse{\boolean{bool}}{T}{F}  \textit{(should be false)}
\end{document}
```

The output of this is:

```
   Start: T
   * item T
   * item F
   End: T (should be false)
```

How might one preserve the value of the boolean set inside an environment so that it is accessible outside?

Comment: `ifthen` and `xifthen` don't allow globally setting a boolean. You'll be luckier with `etoolbox` provided macros, that are much more powerful.

Comment: Besides, if you use `etoolbox` toggles, internally you will only use one macro per toggle (booleans use three).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package `ifthen` (and also `xifthen`) doesn't allow for globally setting booleans. You *could* define global booleans, by adding something like

```
\makeatletter
\def\newglobalboolean#1{%
  \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname if#1\endcsname{%
    \expandafter\let\csname if#1\endcsname\iffalse
    \expandafter\def\csname #1true\endcsname{%
      \global\expandafter\let\csname if#1\endcsname\iftrue
    }%
    \expandafter\def\csname #1false\endcsname{%
      \global\expandafter\let\csname if#1\endcsname\iffalse
    }%
}}
\makeatother
```

After `\newglobalboolean{foo}`, acting with `\setboolean{foo}{true}` or `\setboolean{foo}{false}` will set the boolean globally. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}  % or xifthen

\makeatletter
\def\newglobalboolean#1{%
  \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname if#1\endcsname{%
    \expandafter\let\csname if#1\endcsname\iffalse
    \expandafter\def\csname #1true\endcsname{%
      \global\expandafter\let\csname if#1\endcsname\iftrue
    }%
    \expandafter\def\csname #1false\endcsname{%
      \global\expandafter\let\csname if#1\endcsname\iffalse
    }%
}}
\makeatother

\newglobalboolean{bool}
\setboolean{bool}{true}

\begin{document}
Start: \ifthenelse{\boolean{bool}}{T}{F}

\begin{itemize}
\item{item} \ifthenelse{\boolean{bool}}{T}{F}
\setboolean{bool}{false}
\item{item 2} \ifthenelse{\boolean{bool}}{T}{F}
\end{itemize}

End: \ifthenelse{\boolean{bool}}{T}{F}  \textit{(should be false)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the package `etoolbox` provides many more functions. You get the same output with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newbool{foo}
\setbool{foo}{true}

\begin{document}
Start: \ifbool{foo}{T}{F}

\begin{itemize}
\item{item} \ifbool{foo}{T}{F}
\global\setbool{foo}{false}
\item{item 2} \ifbool{foo}{T}{F}
\end{itemize}

End: \ifbool{foo}{T}{F}  \textit{(should be false)}
\end{document}
```

Note that you can't say `\newbool{bool}`

Answer (score 1):

Please comment the package `\usepackage{ifthen}` and put the below given code:

```
\def\boolean#1{#1}
\def\newboolean#1{\expandafter\newif\csname if#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname  #1false\endcsname}
\def\setboolean#1#2{\expandafter\global\csname #1#2\endcsname}
\def\ifthenelse#1#2#3{\csname if#1\endcsname#2\else#3\fi}
```

See the output.

Comment: Sorry but I think that's a bad solution. Specially your definition of `ifthenelse`. If you do such things you should work with `\expandafter\@firstoftwo`

Comment: One loses all the the features of `ifthen`, in this way. Not that I recommend to use it, but I can't recommend this solution either.

Comment: Yea! That is why I told to comment that package and use the definition (for this particular situation).