# How to keep a boolean value through the frames?

Tags: beamer, tikzducks

My boolean variable managing works with `article` class or within a single frame, but it doesn't work from a frame to another, why?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{toleft}
\setboolean{toleft}{false}     
\newcommand{\duckfamily}[1][1]{%
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=#1]
        \begin{scope}[scale=.15]
        \duck
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=14pt, scale=.1]
        \duck
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=14pt+10pt, scale=.1]
        \duck
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=14pt+20pt, scale=.1]
        \duck
        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
}

\newcommand{\duckdecor}{%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{toleft}}{%
        \duckfamily
        \setboolean{toleft}{false}
        }{%
        \duckfamily[-1]
        \setboolean{toleft}{true}
        } 
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    I would like to type this decor:
    \duckdecor
    alternatively from right to left
    \duckdecor
    and from left to right
    \duckdecor
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    But if it is in different frames\dots  
    \duckdecor
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \dots it doesn't work.
    \duckdecor
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    Why?
    \duckdecor
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

etoolbox has boolean commands that you can prefix with \global:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage{etoolbox} %already loaded by beamer
\newbool{toleft}
\global\booltrue{toleft}
\newcommand{\duckfamily}[1][1]{%
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=#1]
        \begin{scope}[scale=.15]
        \duck
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=14pt, scale=.1]
        \duck
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=14pt+10pt, scale=.1]
        \duck
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=14pt+20pt, scale=.1]
        \duck
        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
}

\newcommand{\duckdecor}{%
    \ifbool{toleft}{%
        \duckfamily
        \global\boolfalse{toleft}
        }{%
        \duckfamily[-1]
        \global\booltrue{toleft}
        }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    I would like to type this decor:
    \duckdecor
    alternatively from right to left
    \duckdecor
    and from left to right
    \duckdecor
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    But if it is in different frames\dots
    \duckdecor
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \dots it doesn't work.
    \duckdecor
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    Why?
    \duckdecor
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{etoolbox}` is no no longer necessary for beamer

Comment: @samcarter yes, but I wanted to show it explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

I used Jagath's answer at [Variable persist outside environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122634/variable-persist-outside-environment/122640#122640), adding 4 lines at the beginning of the preamble and commenting out `\usepackage{ifthen}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
%\usepackage{ifthen}
%
\def\boolean#1{#1}
\def\newboolean#1{\expandafter\newif\csname if#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname  #1false\endcsname}
\def\setboolean#1#2{\expandafter\global\csname #1#2\endcsname}
\def\ifthenelse#1#2#3{\csname if#1\endcsname#2\else#3\fi}
%
\newboolean{toleft}
\setboolean{toleft}{false}     
\newcommand{\duckfamily}[1][1]{%
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=#1]
        \begin{scope}[scale=.15]
        \duck
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=14pt, scale=.1]
        \duck
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=14pt+10pt, scale=.1]
        \duck
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=14pt+20pt, scale=.1]
        \duck
        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
}

\newcommand{\duckdecor}{%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{toleft}}{%
        \duckfamily
        \setboolean{toleft}{false}
        }{%
        \duckfamily[-1]
        \setboolean{toleft}{true}
        } 
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    I would like to type this decor:
    \duckdecor
    alternatively from right to left
    \duckdecor
    and from left to right
    \duckdecor
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    But if it is in different frames\dots  
    \duckdecor
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \dots it doesn't work.
    \duckdecor
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    Why?
    \duckdecor
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is probably not good practice to redefine `\ifthenelse`, but rather to name it as, for example, `\def\gifthenelse#1#2#3{\csname if#1\endcsname#2\else#3\fi}` and then use `\gifthenelse` inside of the `\duckdecor` macro, in lieu of `\ifthenelse`.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I think Sam should get it, as she wrote `tikzducks`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Please not, mine does not solve the problem it's just a workaround.  @ CarLaTeX please accept Ulrike or Stevens answer!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that beamer wraps the content of the frame inside a group, you'd have the same problem with `{ \duckdecor } \duckdecor`.

As a workaround: use a counter instead of the boolean and test if the counter is odd or even.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\newcommand{\duckfamily}[1][1]{%
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=#1]
        \begin{scope}[scale=.15]
        \duck
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=14pt, scale=.1]
        \duck
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=14pt+10pt, scale=.1]
        \duck
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[xshift=14pt+20pt, scale=.1]
        \duck
        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
}

\newcounter{test}
\setcounter{test}{1}

\newcommand{\duckdecor}{%
    \addtocounter{test}{1}%
    \ifodd\value{test}%
        \duckfamily%
    \else%
        \duckfamily[-1]%
    \fi%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \duckdecor
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \duckdecor
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @CarLaTeX I would have been faster, if a colleague of mine would not have chosen the exact second I wanted to submit the answer to come and asked me a question :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX A good question with a clear MWE makes answering easy :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX In TUGBoat? I am looking forward to it!